# unity3D mono.exe stopped working and I can't compile my project

Tags: c#, windows, console, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm currently working on a project and I came across this error.

I was just basically added some C# scripts. I've tested it and it works fine. When I re-opened the unity again. It shows a window '**mono.exe has stopped working**' 2 times.

[image]

After that, unity3D window came up , but I can't compile my project because there's this error

```
Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:Successfully compiled '32' file(s) to 'D:\My Game\Unity Games\Game 3 - Jack and Joe\Temp\Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll'.
```

I'm currently using Unity3D basic v3.5.0 with windows 8 and I've reinstalled unity 2 times, but still no result

Can anyone help? thx b4

Comment: Have you tried to 1.Close Unity, 2.Cleanup the Temp directory & remove the added scripts, 3.Reopen, 4.Re-add the scripts one by one ? This should force Unity to recompile from scratch.

Comment: I have and it's not working. Even I cannot compile a new project. here's the log file crashed: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: mono.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 50773733
  Fault Module Name: browserprotect.dll
  Fault Module Version: 2.6.1249.132
  Fault Module Timestamp: 514c65d5
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0015c047
  OS Version: 6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033

Comment: Can you try updating to 3.5.7. c0000005 exceptions can be tricky to debug and it might be easier to rule out legacy issues due to an old Unity or Mono version.